# print true or false without using if else and any kind of of loop

Tags: if-statement, boolean-logic

My friend recently had an interview in which he was asked **how do you print true or false if you were given input 0 or 1 by user and you have to do this without using if else or any kind of loop?** Unfortunately he didn't asked for the solution from interviewer.I looked for the solution but not able to find related solution anywhere so i thought i should put this question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I leave it open whether 0 represents true or 1.

```
System.out.println(input == 1);
```

This is Java; other languages are similar, though Java is slightly easier.

Here println does a toString on a boolean object.

This Java answer is the purest, a bit like `(bool) (input == 1)`. Giving an actual boolean value. As the question did not state that string representations should be printed.

Otherwise one might assume that the conditional ternary operator `? :` is a form of *if else*, so array indexing is needed.

```
print({"true", "false"}[input]);
```

In C one also could calculate every character numerically.

```
char s[6];
int tupni = 1 - input;
s[0] = (char) ('t' * input + 'f' * tupni);
s[1] = (char) ('r' * input + 'a' * tupni);
s[2] = (char) ('u' * input + 'l' * tupni); 
s[3] = (char) ('e' * input + 's' * tupni); 
s[4] = (char) ('\0' * input + 'e' * tupni);
s[5] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array. For example:

```
# i = user input

array[0] = "false"
array[1] = "true"

print(array[i])
```

You can also use dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript,

```
// userInput is an integer
console.log(Boolean(userInput));
```

In Python,

```
# userInput must be an integer and not string
print(bool(userInput))
```

Answer (score 0):

Good day.

You can use conditional operators or also known as ternary operator for this case.

**Syntax     :        (Condition? true_value: false_value);**
**Example :         (value > 500  ?  0  :  1);**